# Open json editor extension in vscode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the ZainChen json editor extension available through the VSCode marketplace. Here is the [github repository](https://github.com/ZainChen/vscode-json).

So, I installed the extension. I closed my `.json` file, close Visual Studio Code. Re-open VSCode and there's another button on the left hand side (where 'Explorer', 'Search', 'Source Control', 'Debug', and 'Extensions' all reside). The new button is named 'json'. I open my json file. Then I click the 'json' option on the left side.

The header for the sidebar for 'json' says "JSON: Please open the json file.(ZainChen)". I try closing and re-opening the json file. i've right clicked on everything I can think to. I've tried various things in 'View -> Open View' and the only thing I am seeing is the text-based json editor.

Of course, I can work with plain json, but I don't want to.

How can I get the ZainChen json editor extension in VSCode to work for editing my json file?

Answer (score 0):

Closing the braces around the top level schema content fixed the issue for me.

```
{
    "$schema":...
    .
    .
    .
}
```